# how to find the customer custom attribute select box value table

Tags: magento-1.9, php, eav, custom-attributes, multiselect-attribute

I installed the custom_attribute extension, in that I created a field name like "language" with multi select type, also there is a option to add the select box option values.

I added this field into the edit profile page, after the user selects the user language I want to display the selected language to some other page.

May i know in which table the options value will be stored?

See the below screen you will be feel better to answer my post.

1)customer custom multi select attribute(language)

[image]

2)eav attribute table

[image]

3)Customer entity varchar table

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `eav_attribute table`,

- All attributes

In `eav_attribute_option` table,

- Attributes options with reference to reference `attribute_id` in `eav_attribute table`

In `eav_attribute_option_value` table,

- Attribute option values with reference to `option_id` in `eav_attribute_option` table,

In your `customer_entity_varchar` table `15,14,13,12` refers to `option_id` in `eav_attribute_option` table and you can refer the labels for `15,14,13,12` in `eav_attribute_option_value` table

To get the values like `array(12=>'Portuguese',13=>'spanish',14=>'hindi',15=>'tamil')`

```
 /**
     * @var $config  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
     * @var $options Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection
     */
    $storeId   = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
    $attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');
    $values    = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    print_r($values);

    //here is another method
    $options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
    $values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter($storeId)->toOptionArray();
    print_r($values);
```

Comment: i got it your answer,but i want this like array(12=>'Portuguese',13=>'spanish',14=>'hindi',15=>'tamil'), how can i achieve this

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: How to use this for customer/address? @saravanavelu 
I try change Mage_Catalog_Model_Product for Mage_Customer_Model_Address, but don't work, you can help me?

Comment: @saravanavelu See this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201483/how-to-get-the-option-id-of-an-attribute-with-the-value-text